# “loading” message when launching Android app doesn't disappear

Tags: android, webview, loading, progressdialog

I would like to show a "loading..." message when starting my Android app. It should appear for exactly 3 seconds.

I tried to achieve this with the code below, but the problem is that it keeps displaying the "Loading..." message. It disappears when I click on the background, but it's definitely not what I had in mind when using this code.

Can someone please help me out with this one?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//private Button button;
private WebView webView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get webview 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    startWebView("http://example.com");

}

private void startWebView(String url) {

    //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    //When opening a url or click on link

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      


        //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        //Show loader on url load
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            if(progress==3000 && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    });

     // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(url);       

}

// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["loading" message when starting Android app doesn't disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076506/loading-message-when-starting-android-app-doesnt-disappear)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like this:

```
progressDialog.show();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
}, 3000);
```

This will dismiss the progress dialog after 3 seconds automatically